# apt itself update and download packages

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I have Debian SID with the following APT configuration:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

I remove `apt` and `aptitude` scripts from `/etc/cron.daily`.

But apt itself do `update` and `download` operation, and When i use `apt-get dist-upgrade` i prevent to :

```
Need to get 0 B/24.0 MB of archives.
```

It means apt itself updates and downloads upgradble packages.

 `Question is:` How can i disable this feature?

Comment: If you don't want `apt-get` to download stuff, simply don't use `apt-get`? Your question is not quite clear, what are you trying to achieve and how is that not working now?

Comment: I need to use `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`  by hand, not anymore apt itself update and download packages in /var/apt/cache/archives/

Comment: I've never experienced apt downloading updates by itself. If you've removed the cron entries then I wouldn't know how apt would be doing that. Just make sure you don't have any "helpful" packages installed such as `apticron`, `auto-apt`, `apt-watch`, `cron-apt`, etc.